# automatic unwanted continuous anonymous socket calls /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, centos, centos7

I'm getting continuous automatic unwanted anonymous socket calls `GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket 404` on my nodeapp.

I've not implemented any `socket` module in code.
So my question is why I'm getting this 404 requests?

Code was working on `Centos6`, I've just switched to `Centos7` installed `node 0.12.2` and tried running code using `node bin/www` command.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @Siguza good point edited question, actually I have not implemented socket.io anywhere on code, this calls are automatic

Comment: I just had the exact same thing happen on some new AWS instances.  I had to recreate them (thus getting new IPs) 3 times before it went away.  I'm assuming I got a recently used IP addresses or there is/was some general attack going on.  But it was the exact same URI.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm getting it as well.  Just a wall of GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1434564002317-92755 200 0.076 ms - 4
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1434564002320-92756 200 0.077 ms - 4
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1434564002322-92757 200 0.075 ms - 4